# Nuget restore with msbuild extreamly slow on windows container

Tags: docker, msbuild, nuget, docker-for-windows, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to restore the packages in my sln when running MSBuild on my container.

I am using this base container to copy the code and build.

> FROM
> mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

On my local machine the full build an restore takes about 30s. But on the windows image, it takes about 10 minutes. The actual build seems to be quick but, the nuget restore seems to be the issue. In the screenshot below, each line takes about 15-30s. I am not sure why. Is there any thing I can do to dig deeper to figure out/fix the issue?

[image]

These my msbuild commands -

```
$slnFile = "myproject.sln"
$verbosity = "/v:normal"
$mode = "/p:Configuration=Debug"
$outputPath = "C:\Proj\bin"
$msbuildDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"
&$msBuildDir -restore $slnFile
&$msBuildDir $mode $slnFile $verbosity $outputPath
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/perfview is the most advanced (but also difficult to use) performance collection and analysis tool for .NET apps. It does have a `/nogui` command line option, so you might be able to figure out how to get it to collect a NuGet restore, stop the collection, and then copy the etl.zip to the host machine before the image is destroyed.  Otherwise, you might be able to get a similar etl trace from wpr.exe